# Moving items around an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

Hi I'm a little stuck at what to do next. The code is a little game which moves number around. You'll know the game. X is a blank spot which can be moved around.
Here's my code so far.

```
def print_menu():
print('\nPossible moves:')
print('1. up')
print('2. down')
print('3. right')
print('4. left')
print('5. Quit')

puzzle = [[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4'], 
      [' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8'],
      [' 9', '10', '11', '12'], 
      ['13', '14', '15', ' X']]

quit = False

input_line = None

while not quit:
print_menu()

command = int(input("\nChoose a move or press 5 to quit: "))

if command == 1:

elif command == 2:

elif command == 3:

elif command == 4:

elif command == 5:
    quit = True
```

So I have the options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to move the block around and quit the program.
So do I need to declare where the X is to begin with?
Then my thought process for moving the X is to move it into a position either
For up X moves [1 row up in the array, same column ] and 12 moves[1 row down, same column]
Is this on the right track?
I have tried a bit of a search and the method .slice comes up a lot.
Would this be helpful?
Thank you
B

Answer (score 0):

Implementation #1:
Use `dict` of `dict`s instead of the nested `list`s. Then all you have to do is to calculate the index of the new place of `'X'`, and swap their values. For example, if `'X'` found in `puzzle[3][4]` and you want to step it down, you need to replace it with the content of `puzzle[3+4][4]`. So the transformations are pretty simple.

Better implementation:
Write a class 'Board' , with the function `swap(direction)`. You can implement it with the nested `dict` solution behind the scenes.